# Airflow 2.7.1 - Two dags scheduled on same time but not both will run at same time

Tags: python, airflow

I have 2 dags that are scheduled to run every 5 minutes. The issue i'm having is not both of them will simultaneously run. Please see below.

```
*/5 * * * * scheds of both
dagA with task1, task2, task3
dabB with task1, task2

ex:
dagA.task1 (running)
dagB (not even have queues)

dagA.task1 (completed)
dagB.task2 (queued)
dagB.task1 (running)
```

In short, only 1 dag and 1 task will only run.
I checked the config for `parallelism` and value is `32`. Dag code below with very same parameters and task too.

```
@dag(
    dag_id='dagA',
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *', #..every 5 mins
    start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=default_args,
)
--------------------------------------------------------
@dag(
    dag_id='dagB',
    schedule_interval='*/5 * * * *', #..every 5 mins
    start_date=datetime(2023, 9, 1, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=False,
    max_active_runs=1,
    default_args=default_args,
)
def process_gdelt_etl():

    @task(
        retries=1, retry_delay=timedelta(minutes=4)
    )  # they have same task structure too
    def test():
        pass
```

How do I configure or setup these dags to run at same time without waiting to each other dag's tasks to complete? Am I missing some important parameters?

New to Airflow, thanks!

Comment: Which executor are you using? By default, [Airflow uses the SequentialExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/sequential.html), which only runs one task at a time. You'll want to update this to use the [LocalExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/local.html) at a minimum.

Comment: HI @RNHTTR current one is SequentialExecutor, let me change it to your suggestion, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, [Airflow uses the SequentialExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/sequential.html), which only runs one task at a time. You'll want to update this to use the [LocalExecutor](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/core-concepts/executor/local.html) at a minimum.

Comment: this solved the problem, thank you very much!